# HTML5WebView fullscreen youtube video consumes back button click

Tags: java, android, android-webview, youtube-iframe-api

In [`HTML5WebView.java (pastebin link)`](https://pastebin.com/RZwWXQuf)([source](https://code.google.com/archive/p/html5webview/source/default/source)) I have:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    System.out.println("TAG - BACK PRESSED IN WEB VIEW");
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And in the activity that starts the web view I have:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    System.out.println("TAG - BACK PRESSED IN WEB PLAYER ACTIVITY");
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Now when I'm playing an embedded youtube video normally (not fullscreen), both methods are called when I press the back button. When I put the video into fullscreen mode (using the youtube player fullscreen button), none of the methods are called. My only guess is, the back button is being consumed by the web view to undo the fullscreen action (but even that doesn't work).

I am trying to get the back button to immediatly kill the web view, even if  there is a video in fullscreen mode.

[See the problem in action here, had to post it externally because the gif > 2MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrkn7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would delete the embed play of youtube video's or ask google that won't be seen as abuse. Because the embed play of youtube video's can be seen as a abuse of this:

> Your app violates our Device and Network Abuse policy by downloading,
>   monetizing, or otherwise accessing YouTube videos in violation of the
>   YouTube Terms of Service or YouTube API Terms of Service.

More Info: https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/device-network-abuse/ https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms

> For example, your app contains: YouTube background play functionality
>   This is a violation of the YouTube Terms of Service.

That is what I got in my experience because I also made a app where people could watch some YT embed video's but after some updates the app wouldn't be update becuase I got this error that it is abuse so I am warning you that's all.

Comment: There is no background play functionality

Comment: I haven't got that to I just used this by example: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0KTfobsjX9Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> and they still say that.

Comment: There is only foreground video playing, where the video playing is visible.

Comment: I am just warning you. I belive you I did that also not background play I don't know even who I would do that. But they still say that is the reason